# How can I get previous page url when i used location.href?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have used location.href to redirect next page, but now i want to back to this page, how can I do? 
in my case, i cannot use Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery, so any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using location.href to change the URL, your browser is going to kick off a new request/response cycle.  Thus to your server, there is no referrer - this is a whole new request.

The most direct approach to solve your problem would be to add a referrer-url parameter to your new URL, which you can then pick up on the server side.

eg:
    control.location.href = "newpage.aspx?referrer-url=thispage.aspx";

and on the server:
    string referrerUrl = Request["referrer-url"];

Answer (score 0):

If the previous URL is one that you own/can predict (e.g. the user came from page A or page B), you could use a trick like this one: http://www.merchantos.com/blog/makebeta/tools/spyjax